# Detect physical CapsLock position after sending a KEYEVENTF_KEYUP to the Virtual Keyboard Buffer

Tags: winapi, capslock

I am developing a program that will make the CapsLock key work as a control key under Windows. I understand that this can be trivially done with a registry change. Unfortunately, I am not able to run that registry change, nor am I able to run a device driver.

My idea is to watch the keyscans coming over the virtual keyboard. When I see a CapsLock down event, I will send a CapsLock Up event, a second CapsLock down event, a second CapsLock Up event, and then a control-key down event. All of this code works!  However, I have not been able to catch the physical UP action of the CapsLock key.

I've tried reading the CapsLock Up key with both `win32api.GetKeyState()` and `win32api.GetAsyncKeyState()`. After I stuff the CapsLock up event, they both say that the key is up. There seems to be no way to look at the actual hardware and see that it's still down.

Is there a way to catch the events BEFORE they go to the virtual keyboard buffer? If I could do that, I could catch the REAL CapsLock down and Up events. But I can't seem to find it.

I need to be able to do this entirely from the win32 api.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter what language I'm using, because these are WIN32API calls. In this case, the language is Python, but the API is also available for C, C++, C#, Assembler, Pascal, and every other language that runs on Windows.

Comment: Handle `WM_KEY(DOWN|UP)` window messages, or write a keyboard hook using `SetWindowsHookEx()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetKeyState is the state your thread was in when it last received a message. GetAsyncKeyState is the current state. These functions can miss events if you are trying to pull for state changes.

Use a low-level [keyboard hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) to see all input early in the input processing chain. You can also hook your thread with a normal keyboard hook if you don't care about global events.

Comment: That's great. Looks like I can use a Windows Keyboard Hook. I'll need to integrate that into my Python program, and I've found some code to do that now, thanks to your answer. (And @Remy Lebeau's).